# lightbox: how to inject html in cboxLoadedPanel

Tags: jquery, wordpress, lightbox

Apologies for the very generic question.

I have my wordpress site that is using lightbox (I don't even know how many version it exists) . I'd like to open a lightbox window to show the a fragment of a page embedded with the lazy loading.

The site I'm currently working on use a template in which the lightbox is supplied via the shortcode, and using just the shortcode I can't get this working. In fact, although I've been able to inject the code, once I click on the link to get the lightbox pop up, the content of the box is the current page and not the fragment which I can see properly in the HTML code.

If I use the plain html tags, and a couple of extra div that are linked to the "rendered" version of the lightbox code, everything is ok.

I hope this does make sense in some way and somebody can provide an hint towards the solution.

Best
Andrea

Comment: What do you mean with "shortcode"?

Comment: A shortcode is something encloded in bracket, which will be identified during runtime and replaced with full HTML code. http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API